# Docker service: Failed to connect to localhost using browsers due to not supporting IPv6

Tags: docker, localhost, freeze, connection-refused

I am following the Docker [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) for Docker services. After running the services using the following command:

> docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab

I can access it using curl:

> curl -4 http://localhost:4000

but couldn't access the page in Firefox nor Chrome. Both hang when browsing http://localhost:4000. I found that Firefox & Chrome tries to access the page using IPv6, because when I disable IPv6 in Firefox, it worked fine. And `curl -6 http://localhost:4000` doesn't work either. Moreover, http://[::1]:4000/ doesn't work while http://127.0.0.1:4000 works fine. It seems to be similar to this [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24379). Can anyone figure out a workaround?